# AuthenticationManager.SignIn() is not signing in

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-identity

I can get the valid user from the database, create the `ClaimsIdentity` and the `SignIn` method is called without error.

```
public ActionResult SignInConformation(SignInModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Find(model.Username, model.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username and\\or password");
        }
        else
        {
            _authenticationManager.SignOut();
            var claimsIdentity = _userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, claimsIdentity);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

However, when I check if the user is signed in on the view like this:

```
<p>
    Current User: @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                  {
                      @User.Identity.Name
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      @:Unknown
                  }
</p>
```

`IsAuthenticated` returns `false`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was missing the `AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` from the OWIN startup class:

```
var authenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/SignIn"),
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
};

appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(authenticationOptions);
```

It's a shame that there isn't a nice, useful error.  I don't like programs that silently fail.

Comment: I am having the same issue at the moment, production works fine, no issues (production as in connecting from dev machine to production db) but dev env does not work anymore. checked the above but I got this in the Startup class

Comment: You have saved me a ton of time, the OWIN's Authentication.SignIn did not change the CurrentPrincipal for me so I had to do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: Note that DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie is defined in AspNet.Identity. If you're trying to avoid referencing it you can just set this to "ApplicationCookie".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - the problem was that my Home controller was protected with [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] attribute whereas I was trying to log in as User.